# Ito's integral converge in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itô_calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus)

**From wikipedia**:
$$\int_0^tH_tdB_t\equiv \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nH_{t_i}(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})$$
It can be shown that this limit converges in probability. i.e.
$$P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nH_{t_i}(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})\text{ exists})=1$$

Can someone give a proof or a reference how it converges in probability?

It is known that the brownian motion is almost surely of unbounded variation, but can we say the limit doesn't exists almost surely?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Ito's integral is based on the fact that $L^2$ is complete. So the limit you mentioned above is in the sense of $L^2$-convergence indeed. Consequently, $L^2$-convergence implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Why is this actually L2 convergence?

Comment: Since any Brownian motion has unbounded variation, we can't use Riemann-Stieltjes integral to define $\int_{0}^{t}H_sdB_s$, even they look similar, though.You can find more details in some books. For example, Chapter 15 in "Foundations of Modern Probability", Olav Kallenberg.